# Are "any, all and some" used much in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been teaching myself T-SQL for about a year and only now have come across the ANY and ALL operators. I have never seen them used in any sample code until now, are these rarely used and are there preferred operators for getting the same results?

Comment: Can you include the example that you've seen recently that uses them?

Comment: If you don't see a general need for them nobody is forcing you (I hope) to use them. File them away as trivia for now and if, at some later point in time you spot a situation where you think they might apply, dust them off and see if they are a good fit. But if you do have a reason for wanting to get *that exact functionality* (as you seem to indicate at the end of your question), by all means use them for that. It's unlikely that you'll be *penalised* for using them.

Answer (score 2):

I've used `ANY` once in production code. I blogged about it a while ago [here](http://www.spartansql.com/2014/03/using-any-operator.html). But here's the code for posterity:

```
with cte as (
    select * from (values
        ('Name'        ),
        ('StandardCost'),
        ('ListPrice'   )
    ) as x(col)
)
, column_ordinals AS (
    select sys.fn_cdc_get_column_ordinal('Production_Product', col) as [ordinal]
    from cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cdc.[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_Production_Product](
    sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('Production_Product'), 
    sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
    , 'all with mask'
) AS fcgacpp
WHERE [__$operation] = 4 --after update
    AND 1 = ANY (
        select [sys].[fn_cdc_is_bit_set]([ordinal], [__$update_mask])
        from [column_ordinals]
    );
```

Essentially, if any of Name, StandardCost, or ListPrice is represented in the __$update_mask bitmask, return that row from the CDC data. I would agree that `ANY` and `ALL` are not often used, but when you need one of them, they're handy!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  They are used in Microsoft certification exams for Trivial Pursuit-style questioning of topics that aren't actually used much other than to demonstrate all functionality and to make the exams that much harder.  Also perhaps as a profit motive to get more money out of exam takers by increasing the failure rate.

Aside from that, no they're not used much.